# Is it possible to design a SD 3.0 controller in UHS-ii/uhs-i mode using simplified specifications?

Tags: fpga, sd, core, data-storage, data-acquisition

I've been for while looking at how to store sampled data up to a rate of 30MBytes/s; an SD 3.0 host controller core in uhs-ii/uhs-i mode fits the requirements.

I'm not planning to buy the SD full spec and I think it's quite possible to make an SD 2.0 host controller core using just the simplified spec, but is it possible to make an SD 3 host controller in UHS-ii mode too? (SD Assoc offers uhs-ii simplified addendum, but is it enough?). Maybe it doesn't include some crucial details that would lead me to a dead end.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. As this is your first time using these terms could you please define what 'uhs-ii' means.

Comment: Thank you @Sparky256 for your comment :-) for SD cards there are "rating speed" and "speed class". The latter is in the range  [2,4,6,8 or 10 for SD 2.0] OR [uhs-i or uhs-ii for the SD 3.0] (e.g. sd 2.0 with speed class 2 has a minimum speed of 2 Mbytes/s and sd 3.0 with speed class uhs-ii (or better say in mode uhs-ii) has a minimum speed of 30Mbytes/s) hope i could  explain it good for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

The spec is probably cheap compared to the value of one's time, so I don't see much reason to not join the borg for one year and get the spec. Otherwise, there are some ways that are much easier:

1. If on an FPGA: buy the IP for an SD/MMC controller. It will probably be cheaper than joining the borg and the time it'd cost to implement the spec. It's not exactly a trivial protocol when you go to higher speeds, and even its transport layer is more similar to fast Ethernet (cut-off before it reaches digital-analog conversion) than to SPI.
2. Use an MCU with an integrated SD/MMC controller, and a library that goes with it - this is basically turn-key.
3. Use an USB-to-SD bridge, like [Microchip's USB2660](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB2660) - that one can do 35MB/s sustained so may be cutting it close, but I'm sure faster solutions exist. Since USB is an open standard and widely supported, it'll be way easier to implement a dedicated host USB port to interface with a USB bridge than perhaps dealing with SD.

I'm not quite sure why the SD borg (now two borgs, since one wasn't enough, obviously) keeps those specs behind a paywall - nobody implements SD for pleasure, pretty much everyone does it to actually use SD cards as a storage medium in their products. So the SD borg founders will get their money no problem. And as for outfits that make counterfeit SD cards without proper licensing: they obviously have the spec already and that didn't stop them, and opening up the spec doesn't mean that using SD logo etc. won't require separate licensing and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I read simplified spec and I think that it is sufficient to build the UHS-II host.
Maybe some things are explained in a simplified way, but it is possible to check them on the builded prototype and improve it if they did not work.

The bigger problem is probably implementing this in FPGA.
My favorite FPGA manufacturer, Lattice, not helping because requires a subscription license to use SERDES FPGAs (free license is only for non-SERDES FPGAs). I'll probably must switch to XILINX.

The commands look the same as in SD Legacy mode. Difference is mainly in the PHY, due to 8b10b and SERDES coding (and maybe in CRC to).

What FPGA do You plan to use for this?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Note that this site doesn't operate like a typical forum. Please avoid asking questions within your answers, as this opens the door for discussion.

Comment: There's no reason most modern FPGA shouldn't be able to do the most of the faster speeds, with 1.8V IO the fastest SD switching rate is 208Mhz which isn't terribly fast for most midrange FPGAs... I doubt you even need the SERDES hardware which is mostly for implementing much higher speed interfaces like PCIe etc...